# How to use slot scope correctly within vuejs 2.5.x?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to utilize a [slot-scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute) functionality within our Vue application **(old syntax v2.5.x)**: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute and it just doesn't work.

This is my **child component**:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      foo: "bar"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Which I try to use from the **main component** as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ChildComponent msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!">
      <ul slot-scope="props">
        <li>foo: {{props.foo}}</li>
        <li>msg: {{props.msg}}</li>
      </ul>
    </ChildComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "./components/ChildComponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is a link to codesandbox's example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-lg8r3

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up normal slots and scoped slots.

Assuming you want scoped slots you would need to change this:

```html
<slot></slot>
```

to this:

```html
<slot :foo="foo" :msg="msg"></slot>
```

They won't be passed automatically.

Comment: Ok, it works. But I didn't see this in official tutorial, did I miss it? May you point me where it's written please?

Comment: @Anatoly It's covered in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots. Note that the behaviour of `<slot>` in the child hasn't changed between 2.5 and 2.6, it's only the attributes of the parent that changed.

Comment: thank you @skirtle, I see it now. They mixed functionality from new and old versions in the same manual and it's confused me. Thank you very much!